# rails - making a reusable User.find

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have many places in my program where I use the: `@user = User.find(params[:id])`

Now, I wanted to make a new method in `ApplicationController` so that all my `controllers` would be able to use the method so that I would not have to repeat my self so much.

```
def find_user(params[:id])
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

So now when I want to display users in some controller, I just type the `find_user(params[:id])` in an action. But this doesn't seem to work for some reason.

Comment: Exactly what do you achieve by defining that method? Byte wise, it has the exact same length. Design wise, all your controllers now have a method which they may not need while the `User.find` was nicely encapsulated within the User class. Is your method more complex than what you have shared?

Comment: do you get any error ? maybe u can try to debug by seeing what the method returns. maybe you are reinitializing the variable somewhere below again.

Comment: Well basically I am just trying to practice different things, even if they are not the most useful Byte wise.

Comment: there's nothing to achieve by adding this method.... but actually knowing what doesn't work is the first step in being able to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I'd like to say that although it's a common call, I would not make a method for it, because it is already essentially just calling one method, but here:

You're making it a little too complicated:

In the application controller

```
def find_user(user_id)
  @user = User.find(user_id)
end
```

In the controller you're using it in

```
find_user(params[:id])
```

---

Alternatively if for some reason you don't want to write params everytime

In the application controller

```
def find_user(paramsicle) # params might be reserved
  @user = User.find(paramsicle[:id])
end
```

In the controller you're using it in

```
find_user(params)
```

---

EDIT:  It'd probably be helpful if I explained why yours doesn't work...

Yours is fine, except that method arguments (the stuff in the parenthesis) should just be a identifier except in special cases (optional arguments, the *args things).  Read more about it [here](http://www.skorks.com/2009/08/method-arguments-in-ruby/).  The problem wasn't with params, but with trying to access id while still in the arguments section.  That's why it was find to call paramsicle[:id] afterwards.

Comment: But if I now take the last option, and enter something into `find_user(params)`, lets say `find_user(4)`, would it not do something like this in the method I defined: `@user = User.find(4[:id])`?

Comment: in that case, just use the first method.  Because the first method is really just calling `User.find` on whatever is passed to it.  I updated my answer to explain why you can't have the definition that way, but the link I posted might help even more